# Is GPG's MDC a valid method of identifying file corruption?

Tags: gnupg

I understand that GPG, when encrypting symmetrically using AES-256, uses a Modification Detection Code. Will this ensure that any corruption (e.g. bitrot) of the encrypted file can be flagged, as opposed to passing silently? How does this protection compare to taking a sha256sum hash of the encrypted file and using that to determine integrity of the encrypted data?

N.B. I'm thinking in a backup context, where my main objective is to archive a large file, and I want to ensure that it is both encrypted, and that any corruption in the archive can be detected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Sym. Encrypted Integrity Protected Data Packet](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4880#section-5.13) together with the [Modification Detection Code Packet](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4880#section-5.14) have been introduced to prevent a set of attacks on the OpenPGP protocol which built upon modifying the cryptotext and using a so-called decryption oracle to partially guess the original plain text.

With those two packets, modifications to the cryptotext can be detected. This of course also includes random bit flips. They do not provide a cryptographic signature though. In contrast to storing an additional SHA256 checksum, the difference is the MDC packet uses SHA-1: but both should be sufficient for a detection of random corruption. The modification detection is also limited to the encryption stream, not the OpenPGP headers/metadata. In both cases (plain SHA256 hash and MDC packet) you will not be able to restore the rotten bits, you can only detect modifications.

You can easily try by modifying the crypto text of an encrypted OpenPGP message.